# F1 visa renewal - documents required for visa interview

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, student-visa

When renewing an F1 visa with a valid I20 (valid upto 2017) at the consulate in india what are the supporting documents needed? Immigration help only lists supporting documents as supporting documents for the visa type which includes GRE scores and all. Does anyone know what documents are needed for visa interview for F1 renewal?

Comment: This is more appropriate for expatriates.SE>

Comment: If closing a question because it fits better on Expatriates, please flag it for the moderators and add a comment that it has been flagged. I did flag it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much the same documents as you took first time. Valid I-20, financial support document, etc. I would also carry a copy of resume, transcript, letter from advisor or you department saying you are in good standing.

Also check with you international student advisor.